# Redirect to url then again redirect to main url

Tags: php, javascript

I know it is really confusing. Let me explain:

I want to open the urls on my site (http://domain.com) to a (http://domain.com/url='the submitted url') and then the submitted url is opened.

Eg: When we open any other site link from Google+ let the example

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WRpX7tkwejU

it redirects to

[http://plus.url.google.com/url?sa=z&n=1333340186022&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DWRpX7tkwejU&usg=whZv4BO7Gcrco_vivlnhaz27Wpk.](http://plus.url.google.com/url?sa=z&n=1333340186022&url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WRpX7tkwejU&usg=whZv4BO7Gcrco_vivlnhaz27Wpk.)

and then the original site is opened. I want some thing similar.

Comment: "I want some thing similar" --- so? Have you done any research already?

Comment: i searched but no success..!!

Comment: hmm, Not bad. :P They use (imo) a htaccess configuration to rename `/redirect.php?to=<link>` to `/url=<link>` where `redirect.php` takes the link as `$_GET` and redirects you to that link.

Comment: @The Jumping Frog plz give a detailed working answer please!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. On your site, replace any regular external link like http://example.com with, say, `/redirect.php?url=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com`. Make sure to `urlencode` the original domain name.
2. In `redirect.php`, redirect the user:

   ```
   header('Location: ' . $_GET['url']);
   ```

Comment: i am not getting it. please elaborate

Comment: @deceze: you probably might buy a flight and teach OP how to program ;-)

Comment: @zerkms If the OP pays for it, sure. I always wanted to visit India (just guessing nationalities here, Navneet). :)